# how to prove that $\overline {A^c}$ $\subseteq {(A^\circ)}^{c} $

Tags: calculus, general-topology

As part of my proving that $\overline {A^c}$ = ${(A^\circ)}^{c} $, I want to prove that there is containment from both sides. I succeeded in proving the first one which is:

- ${(A^\circ)}^{c}$ $\subseteq$ $\overline {A^c}$)

  by replacing $\overline {A^c}$ with $A^{c}$. now I want to prove the other containment    $\overline {A^c}$ $\subseteq {(A^\circ)}^{c} $, how do I do this?

Comment: You know that $A^c\subset (A^\circ)^c$. Since $A^\circ$ is open, $(A^\circ)^c$ is closed. A closed subset contains the closure of any subset of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\in\bar{A^c}$, so that $x$ is an element of all closed sets $D$ that contain $A^c$. Equivalently, the $D^c$ are open sets contained in $A$, so $x$ is not contained in any such open set, meaning that $x$ is not contained in the interior of $A$. But then $x$ is contained in its complement, i.e. in $(A^{\circ})^c$.

Comment: I got your idea. but can u clarify what u mean by "all closed sets D that contain $A^{c}$? do you mean $A^{c}$ $\cup$ $A^{c}$' ?

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani , I use the definition of the closure. By definition, the closure $\bar{B}$ of a set $B$ is the intersection of all closed sets that contain $B$. So if $x\in\bar{B}$, then $x$ is contained in all closed sets containing $B$.

Answer (score 0):

$$A^{\circ}:=A\setminus \overline{A^c}$$

Therefore $$(A^{\circ})^c=A^c\cup\overline{A^c}\supset \overline{A^c}$$

Since $B\subset \overline{B}$ for all $B$ we could have actually put an equality above.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in \overline{A^c}$. We want to show it is in $(A^\circ)^c$. So suppose it is not. Then $x \in A^{\circ} (\subseteq A)$. This is an open set that contains $x$, so as $x \in \overline{A^c}$ we know it should intersect $A^c$. But a subset of $A$ cannot intersect $A^c$, contradiction. So $x \in (A^\circ)^c$.